Is consensual incest between a brother and sister wrong (sinful)?
According to Hinduism. Is consensual incest between a brother and sister allowed?
For example let's say the siblings are of same age, they love eachother romantically, and wish to be together.
Is this wrong? And if it is Wrong,
what kind of punishment will they receive?
1 For being in love.
2 having sexual intercourse.
Please provide some scripture text thank you.

Smritis like Manusmriti and Parasharasmriti have verses that oppose incest. Here's an answer that gives some scriptural evidence. Moreover, some smritis like Gautama Smriti and Vashishta Dharma Sutra even forbid marriages between people who are related to each other by a common ancestor by 6 degrees on the father's side (or 4 degrees on the mother's side). Here's scriptural evidence for that. So I would say Hinduism is generally quite opposed to incest.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
